# how to insert string into a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, business-logic

```
var myeleArr = {
                    advertiser :{},
                    campaign :{},
                    strategy :{},
            };
```

i want to insert some string into myeleArr.campaign object, so i am doing as shown below, 
but console displays as *Object # has no method 'push'*

```
myeleArr.campaign.push('<span class="'+myele['status']+'"></span>'+myele['name']+'');
```

Can some body help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend for campaign to be a string, then set

```
myeleArr.campaign = "my string";
```

If you intend for campaign to hold a bunch of strings, in order, where the strings aren't referred to by name, then make it an array:

```
myeleArr.campaign = [];
myeleArr.campaign.push("My String");
myeleArr.campaign[0]; // "My String"
```

If you intend for campaign to hold a bunch of strings by name, then give your current campaign object named properties, and set each of those named properties to be a string:

```
myeleArr.campaign = {
    title : "My Title",
    type  : "Campaign Type",
    description : "Campaign Description",
    num_managers : 7,
    isActive : true
};

myeleArr.campaign.title; // "My Title"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `push` function is used to add an item to an array but `campain` isn't defined as an array.

Try with this :

```
 var myeleArr = {
        advertiser :{},
        campaign :[], // this makes an array
        strategy :{},
 };
```

Or, if you want to have only one value in `campaign`, don't use `push` but simply

```
myeleArr.campaign = '<spa...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `push` method is meant for javascript arrays. So, instead of object literals, if you change campaign, etc keys to point to array literals, you'd be able to push. i.e. -

```
var myFoo = { advertiser: [], campaign: [], strategy: [] };
myFoo.campaign.push('my stuff');
```

Also, if you just want to assign a string to campaign, you could simply -

```
var myeleArr = {};
myeleArr.campaign = "<span>...";
```

Checkout the javascript console in [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) under Google Chrome, or install nodejs, both are good places to try out these things when you're not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Make the campaign as an `array` instead of an `object` .
Because push is a method on arrays and not objects

```
campaign :[],
```